# SQL literal row numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Anyone know of an easy way to label rows with a literal label

ie

```
1  | first | data

2  | second| data

3  | third | data

4  | fourth| data

5  | fifth | data
```

Other then using a conditional ordinal.  Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be the whole word (e.g. fourth) or could it be a hybrid (e.g. 4th)?

Comment: @SteveChambers it would need to be the full text unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have any built in feature for this. Please see the answers to [Is there a way to have SQL Server format a number into ordinal form?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6084/is-there-a-way-to-have-sql-server-format-a-number-into-ordinal-form).

In the comments of that question, there is a pointer to a site which contains some functions which will do this. I can't speak for the quality of these - you'll have to see for yourself.

http://www.novicksoftware.com/udfofweek/Vol2/T-SQL-UDF-Vol-2-Num-9-udf_Num_ToWords.htm

You can, of course, write your own.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is **NO** there is no such thing in SQL Server.

There can be ceratin workaround for this. Although I am not very sure how much effective they are but you can convert the int to string for what you want to achieve.

But certainly SQL Server does not provide any such facility or inbuilt feature.

Comment: so this should be a comment right? unless you'll expand your answer more.

Comment: @491243:- Correct me if I am wrong but do you think there is any other answer then NO for this question. P.S. Definitely I am trying to figure out some workaround . But certainly the answer to question is NO

Comment: @RahulTripathi I would then be interested in what you think is the best (least pain in the ass way to do it).

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna:- I cannot guarantee that this is the best approach but you can give it a try to convert integer to string for that column.(Although I dont understand why you want to do that)